# What would be the best way to have object properties also contain data source?

Tags: python, data-modeling, pydantic

I have a project where I'm blending various data sources together into an instance of an object. Different attributes come from different sources, but I would like to keep track of which pieces of data came from where. The project is in Python and currently using Pydantic to handle some serialization. How would you go about this? Is there a way to extend a Pydantic field to handle this scenario? The data source will be known at run time/object instantiation, not necessarily object definition.

General flow might go something like this:

1. Create sparse object from Source A (attributing all object properties to Source A)
2. Create another sparse object from Source B (attributing all object properties to Source B)
3. Save to a data store with attributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can attach attributes to objects at runtime. Just create a store object with a dictionary as attribute where you keep the sources and then do the following:

```
class Store():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sources = {}


# Some custom object A
class ObjectA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_0 = 3
        self.a_1 = lambda t: str(t)

# Some custom object B
class ObjectB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_0 = dict(foo=3, bar=4)
        self.b_1 = set([7, 8])
       
store = Store()
obj_a = ObjectA()
obj_b = ObjectB()

for obj in (obj_a, obj_b):
    # Get all attributes except the special ones
    attributes = [t for t in dir(obj) if not t.startswith("__")]
    
    # Add them to the store as attributes and save their sources as
    # class name in store.sources
    for attr in attributes:
        setattr(store, attr, getattr(obj, attr))
        store.sources.update({attr: type(obj)})
```

which gives you

```
store.sources
{'a_0': __main__.ObjectA,
 'a_1': __main__.ObjectA,
 'b_0': __main__.ObjectB,
 'b_1': __main__.ObjectB}
```

and you can do

```
print(store.a_0)
print(store.a_1)
print(store.b_0)
print(store.b_1)
```

which results in

```
3
<function ObjectA.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001837CDBE5E0>
{'foo': 3, 'bar': 4}
{8, 7}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the in-depth answer with examples! This is similar to how I've found myself leaning too, just a different object that contains such meta data that's set attribute set. Thank you!

Comment: @four43 You are welcome son. Does that answer your question then or are you looking for something else? If not, then feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm curious to see if there are any other approaches out there. I'll make sure to flag an answer in a few days.